# Differences in using super() when extending a class

Tags: javascript, class, extends

I'm learning about creating a new class, extending it and subclassing. I don't understand the following:

- Why in extending the class in example #2 both the `constructor()` and the `super()` use `length` as an argument?
- If `super()` in example #2 is supposed to access the parent class Polygon, shouldn't it use as arguments `height` and `width` to access them in the Polygon class instead of `length` (like it does in example #4)? If not, why?

Source code is: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/classes-es6/index.html

```
// Example 1: Creating a new class (declaration-form)
// ===============================================================

class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.name = 'Polygon';
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  sayName() {
    console.log('Hi, I am a ', this.name + '.');
  }

  sayHistory() {
    console.log('"Polygon" is derived from the Greek polus (many) ' +
      'and gonia (angle).');
  }
}


// Example 2: Extending an existing class
// ===============================================================

class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor(length) {
    super(length, length);
    this.name = 'Square';
  }
  get area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
  set area(value) {
    this.area = value;
  }
}

let s = new Square(5);

s.sayName();
console.log('The area of this square is ' + s.area);

// Example 4: Subclassing methods of a parent class
// ===============================================================

class Rectangle extends Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    super(height, width);
    this.name = 'Rectangle';
  }
  sayName() {
    console.log('Sup! My name is ', this.name + '.');
    super.sayHistory();
  }
}

let r = new Rectangle(50, 60);
r.sayName();
```

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense that a square takes only one argument - the length of one of its sides. But if the Square is a type of Polygon, Polygons here require *two* arguments, a height and a width.

If one instantiates a Square, that square needs to call `super` to run the Polygon constructor, which expects two arguments, `height` and `width`. In the `Square` constructor, those are the same - the `length` variable, hence the call

```
super(length, length);
```

Example 4 is different because it's a `Rectangle`, not a `Square`. Rectangles accept two arguments, a height and a width, just like Polygons, so both the `Rectangle` constructor and the `Polygon` constructor are called with `(height, width)`, and the `super` call reflects that:

```
super(height, width);
```

Comment: you are everywhere

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance. An additional clarifying question: in the Rectangle case, is there a relation between the variables names `height` and `width` used in the Polygon class and by `super()`?  Would `super ()` work correctly even if I write `super(lenght1, length2)`, while still keeping `(height, width)`in the Polygon class ?

Comment: @user3926863 If `lenght1` and `length2` were variables in scope at the time you called `super`, yes, you could do that - a child class's constructor arguments don't have to have anything to do with the parent class's constructor arguments.

Comment: Thank you again @CertainPerformance. Given what you said, in extending an existing class - if a child class's constructor arguments don't have to have anything to do with the parent class's constructor arguments - in which case is it required that I specify the arguments for super() and constructor ()? If I just leave them with no arguments, would it still work correctly?

Comment: @user3926863 If the parent constructor needs data from the child constructor scope, it should be passed through `super`. If you call `super` with no arguments, the parent class's constructor's arguments (if any) will all be `undefined` https://jsfiddle.net/75s296kg/ It depends on the parent - sometimes you can do that, sometimes calling `super` with no arguments will result in errors (like if the parent expects an argument to be a string, and tries to invoke a string method on it)